# Fill cell array with a certain value in matlab

Tags: matlab

First question: say I have a 3x3 cell array, lets call it A. So, if I want to fill A{1:2, 1:2} with the same cell array, how do I do it. MatLab requires both sides of the '=' to have the same number of elements. How do I assign the same value (a 2x1 cell) to A{1:2, 1:2}, in a single instruction?

Second question: I want to create a probability generator (not sure if it's the correct term) that will pick between a certain amount of option, based on a prior probability. For example, say that I want to randomly pick between A, B, and C, based on the following probabilities:

```
P(A) = .4
P(B) = .5
P(C) = .1
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: also "A useless title from a StackOverflow noobie".  Try to write a title that highlights what's unique or significant about your question.  Hint: neither "having a question" nor "being a noobie" is unique to you in any way.

Comment: next, the button you clicked was "Ask **A** Question", not "Ask a bunch of questions".  One question per post.

Comment: Indeed, you are still in time to change your title. please do it.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, `repmat` should work well.

For an example, see http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/8977

For your second question, combine `<`, `cumsum`, and `find`.  If you want a more detailed explanation, open a second question covering just the probability generation.

Comment: Thank you and sorry about the lack of descriptive title and posting 2 questions in 1 post